# How to run plugin localy using lazy or how to setup plugin project for nvim

Tags: neovim

project looks like this

```
    example.nvim
       - example
          - lua
            - example 
              - init.lua
       - plugin
         - example.lue
```

I tried setting path to root dir of project and tried to setting it directly to .lua files

```
  return {
        dir = 'path/to/local/folder',
        dev = true,
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use lazy package manager and willing to use lazyload, you can try my directory layout like this

```
.
├── init.lua    | Neovim initialization file
├── after/      | Standard auto-loading 'after' base directory
│   └── plugin/ | Auto-loading 'plugin' configs
├── ftdetect/   | Detect filetype
└── lua/        | Lua base directory
    ├── config/ | Plugin configs that ARE lazy-loaded via explicit 'require'
    └── custom/ | plugin-manager, mappings and options configs
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a way to setup plugin project localy. All props to M4xshen, check his [blog](https://m4xshen.dev/posts/develop-a-neovim-plugin-in-lua/) for more detail info.**

Create a new directory on your local machine

> mkdir ~/example.nvim

2. Install plugin

> return {
> dir = "~/example.nvim"
> }

3. cd to the directory

> cd ~/example.nvim

At the root of your plugin, create a structure like this:

```
example.nvim/ 
├── lua 
│   └── example 
│       └── init.lua 
└── plugin
     └── example.lua
```

plugin/

The files inside plugin/ folder will be executed when Neovim starts. Try to add the following line to example.lua:

```
print("plugin/example.lua is executed!")
```

Open a new Neovim instance after that, you’ll see the string printed because Neovim runs the Lua code of the file.